# Digital Watch in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I want to use Digital watch in cakephp according to time zone I provide.

I'm able to show current time according to user timezone.

In details..
I'm working on a project. I have a table in database where I have seved users details like.
First Name
Last Name
Timezone
and other details.

I want to show the digital clock on user's profile according to timezone stored in the database.

Kindly help me how can I do that.

Thanks

Comment: When you tried to use [the time helper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/time.html#using-the-helper) to display the localized time what problem did you have?

Answer (score 0):

You ned to use Javascript to display clock at page. You can use any of it, just goole and select clock you like. For example [this from w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_timing_clock) it will display clock in the user's current timezone.

If you still want to show clock in predefined timezone just set starting values from PHP instead this line from above example:

```
var today=new Date();
```

use something like

```
var today=new Date(<?=$current_timestamp_in_selected_timezone?>);
```

Use PHP function to build `$current_timestamp_in_selected_timezone` `mktime()` or `date()`

Note that you need to write javascript code inside your `View` to use such technic what isn't a good approach. In good application you need to write code of your JS clock in JS file, put it into `app/webroot/js`, include that file [in layout](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#layouts) or call [inside controller](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html) and than pass variable from PHP. How to do that read here: [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)